# How to add confidence intervals to cumulated timeseries

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, arima

I'm forecasting a timeseries with arima, and want to plot the cumulated predictions. How can i add the according confidence intervals? I'ts my understanding that I can't simply cumulate the intervals as well, right? But how can I add them?

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

AirPassengers

model <- Arima(AirPassengers)

model <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)


prediction <- forecast(model, h = 12)

prediction_df <- data.frame(time = 1:12,
  point = prediction$mean %>% as.numeric,
                            lo_95 = prediction$lower[,2] %>% as.numeric,
                            hi_95 = prediction$upper[,2] %>% as.numeric)



ggplot(prediction_df, aes(x = time, y = point)) +
  geom_line() +
  ylim(0, 700) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo_95, ymax = hi_95), alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue")



prediction_cum <- data.frame(time = 1:12,
                             point = cumsum(prediction$mean),
                             lo_95 = cumsum(prediction$lower[, 2]),
                             hi_95 = cumsum(prediction$upper[, 2])
                                            )


ggplot(prediction_cum, aes(x = time, y = point)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo_95, ymax = hi_95), alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue")
```

Comment: It's hard to get confidence intervals for a cumulative sum of predictions. $\text{var}(\hat{Y}_1 + \hat{Y}_2) = \text{var}(\hat{Y}_1) + \text{var}(\hat{Y}_2) + 2 \text{cov}(\hat{Y}_1, \hat{Y}_2)$. The first two terms are easy. But R's `predict` doesn't give the covariance between predictions, for good reasons too; with 100 observations that is a $100 \times 100$ matrix. In an OLS model or GLM, it could be done easily by taking the `vcov` and `coef` objects and multiplying them by the model matrix. I'm not sure about ARIMA and its error terms though...

Comment: See https://otexts.org/fpp2/aggregates.html

Answer (score 2):

One approach which I have incorporated into AUTOBOX ( a piece of software that I have helped to develop) is to generate via monte carlo predictions via bootstrapping. The predictions are based upon the model errors and the possible changing forecast variance. These forecasts are saved to the operating system and available for recall. For example one can then take the family of forecasts for 1 period out and for 2 periods out and randomly aggregate them to create a family of forecasts for the sum of the first two periods out etc.

This feature is also available to causal models thus uncertainties in the forecast are based upon the distribution of uncertainties in each of the predictors. Another interesting feature is the introduction of incorporating uncertainties due to pulses (one time anomalies) providing more realistic prediction intervals.

Hope this helps you and others ....